# How can I stop my windows from rattling when I shut a door?

Tags: walls, windows, construction

I love where I live, but I don't love my house's construction. It has 24" center studs, lots of space in the walls, and every time an exterior door is shut the windows in nearly all rooms rattle. The roof-mounted AC compressor also induces more vibration than I care for inside. With young kids at home whom I would sometimes prefer to stay asleep, I'd like to find solutions to quiet down these transient noises.

Would adding diagonal bracing ([What are these horizontal & diagonal 'studs' in the wall called?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31336/what-are-these-horizontal-diagonal-studs-in-the-wall-called)) be helpful in transmitting vibrations to the ground instead of the walls? Would new windows be more effective? What can I do to make my house more livable?

Comment: Are your studs 2x4 or 2x6...?

Comment: Replacing windows would probably fix it, but can be expensive.  Most well installed windows in good condition should not rattle.  Windows in poor condition can usually be easily fixed for much less than new windows.   Adding pictures of your windows to your question would help.

Comment: Just a suggestion:  Find a way to slow down the closing of the exterior doors, like a hydraulic door closer. I obviously DK if its air pressure change that rattles your windows or the door closing too fast (slamming). In either case, slowing down the rate of close *MIGHT* fix your problem.  You could test this idea by slowly closing the door and see what happens.

Comment: Tell us more about the windows - are they 2-pane (or more) with grid sandwiched between the panes of glass?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Could reduce or eliminate the air pressure variable by leaving one door standing open while closing another - or even open the windows themselves a few inches and then close a door.

Comment: As you are finding out... if your house has external built with 24 OC framing... there will be a myriad of "shaking" issues, the window just being one of them.   I live near an area that has lower building codes... and they have prefab house built with 24OC 2x4... and it is crazy, I can literally shake a house.    So unless people that answer have witnessed this understand... don't throw money at short term things...   Like new windows, the vibrations might cause seal failures after x amount of time.

Comment: Do you own or rent the house? That will help determine the extent of fixes that can be suggested, as renters aren't allowed (usually) to do much work.

Comment: A quick fix would be to make a number of very small wooden wedges that could be used in any window gaps to stop any vibration or noise.

Comment: @DMoore -- yeah, 2x4 24"OC framing is about as min-spec as you can get.  2x6 24"OC though...probably shouldn't be this ill-behaved >.>